# How to avoid Multi-user PHP Cache add up?

Tags: php, caching, user-input, apc, opcache

I am developing a website using PHP and I want to store data on my user/browser's cache so I can keep the data through PHP pages without moving it all the time through `GET` or `POST`. I have used APC and APCu functions to make this work (Because I need the key-value system).

However, I think I'm using the system cache (?) instead of the user's cache so when I try to run my program at multiple computers the cache of these users adds up. I would like this to be individual for each computer/user. I cannot find almost any APC/APCu functions whose parameters include the cache type of 'user' instead of 'system' (default) -- (like in `apc_clear_cache('user')` for example)

Am I not using the right caching mechanism (APC, APCu, OPCache), am I missing parameters, or is it something else?

Comment: None of the things you've mentioned will cache things anywhere but on the server. The easiest thing that you can do to leverage client-side caching is to set the appropriate [caching headers](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers) on the response, which will also help you leverage CDNs and other downstream caches. If you want anything beyond _that_ then you need to look at moving portions of your application to JS which can leverage more client-local storage options.